# How to find the probability that the insect is within one unit of the z-axis?

Tags: calculus

An insect is flying in $R^3$. It's position is described by continous random variables having a joint density function:

$$f(x,y,z) = \frac{1}{\pi^2} \frac{1}{z^2+1}e^{-x^2-y^2}$$

Find the probability that the insect is within one unit of the z-axis.

I did attempt this question and got the answer $\frac{1}{2}(1 - e^{-1})$. I am doubting myself that this is indeed correct. I found the jacobian to be $rcos^2(\theta)+rsin^2(\theta) = r$.

Could someone please verify that my answer is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using [cylindrical coordinates](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CylindricalCoordinates.html) (indeed with Jacobian $r$) and Fubini, we get
\begin{split}\int_{\text{Cylinder around $z$-axis}} f(x,y,z)\,\mathrm d(x,y,z)&=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\color{blue}{\int_{\mathbb R}\mathrm dz}\color{orange}{\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\theta}\color{green}{\int_0^1\mathrm dr}\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{z^2+1}}\color{green}{\exp(-r^2)\cdot r}\right)
\\
&=\color{green}{\frac{e-1}{2e}}\frac{1}{\pi^2}\color{orange}{\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\theta}\color{blue}{\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{1}{z^2+1}\mathrm dz}\\
&=\color{green}{\frac{e-1}{2e}}\frac{\color{orange}{2\pi}\cdot\color{blue}\pi}{\pi^2}\\
&=\frac{e-1}{e}.
\end{split}

So I have two times your result.

Comment: Very helpful. I see where I went wrong. Thank you.